# How to add defaultOption to AsyncSelect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using Async react-select for my component and can't solve an issue with default Options . Docs couldn't help me , because there were not such an example related to my issue .

```
const campaignToOption = campaign => ({value: campaign.id, label: campaign.name});

const loadOptionsWrapper = fetchAll =>
    input => fetchAll({
        _limit: 10000,
        q: input,
        _sort: 'name',
        _order: 'asc',
    }).then(campaigns => _(campaigns).reject('meta').map(campaignToOption).values());

const defaultProps = {
    options: [],
    placeholder: 'Campaign: Not selected',
};

const CampaignFilter = props => {
    return <Async
        defaultOptions={[{label: 'All Campaigns', value: '-2', group: true}]}
        loadOptions={loadOptionsWrapper(props?.actions?.fetchAllCampaigns)}
        {...defaultProps}
        {...props}
    />;
};

export default CampaignFilter;
```

I want to add an option which will let the users to select all options . So in case of AsyncSelect , options are being loaded asynchronously. Docs say we can use defaultOptions.

> The defaultOptions prop determines "when" your remote request is
>   initially fired. There are two valid values for this property.
>   Providing an option array to this prop will populate the initial set
>   of options used when opening the select, at which point the remote
>   load only occurs when filtering the options (typing in the control).
>   Providing the prop by itself (or with 'true') tells the control to
>   immediately fire the remote request, described by your loadOptions, to
>   get those initial values for the Select.

**And when us it , i only get that default option in my dropdown like this`** 
[image]

**But my goal is to get a component like in this pic `**

[image]

Comment: Your first picture shows an option 'All campaigns', but I don't see how that is added in your code. Looks like you are setting options to an empty array in `defaultProps`. Where did that  'All campaigns' option come from? 

Also I think it would be helpful if you can provide a simplified codesandbox.

Comment: I updated my code...

Comment: When you start typing, do the other options show up?

Comment: Yes , it shows the options list filtered by input value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve your desired result is to add a custom option to whatever  `campaignToOption` returns.

For example you could use this method to append a special option to your array:

```
const appendSpecialOption = filteredOptions => {
  return [
    { label: "All Campaigns", value: "-2", group: true },
    ...filteredOptions
  ];
};
```

Keep `defaultOptions` to True (not an array).

Here is a simplified version of your scenario but I hope it helps:

[image: Edit react-codesandboxer-example]

Comment: Looks like it solves the problem and as i looked around and didn't find anything else ... thank

Comment: @mehamasum cold you take a look on this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303961/use-spread-operator-to-combine-multiple-arrays-fetching-data-in-react-js/

Comment: @mehamasum it will be very helpful