# Use spread operator to combine multiple arrays fetching data in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement something like infinity scrolling on my application. This is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";

const WithPromises = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]); //here should be added all data
  const [scrolll, setScrolll] = useState();
  const filterData = (inputValue) => {
    const req = fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=15&_page=${page}`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        const fetchedData = res.map(({ title }) => {
          return {
            label: title,
            value: title
          };
        });
        page > 1 && setAllData([...allData, ...fetchedData]);
        return [...fetchedData, allData];
      });
    return req;
  };

  const promiseOptions = (inputValue) => {
    return filterData(inputValue);
  };

  const scroll = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    setScrolll(e);
    promiseOptions();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(page + 1);
  }, [scrolll, page]);

  return (
    <AsyncSelect
      cacheOptions
      onMenuScrollToBottom={scroll}
      isClearable={true}
      isSearchable={true}
      defaultOptions
      loadOptions={promiseOptions}
    />
  );
};

export default WithPromises;
```

How you can see, i increment the page when the scroll section is at the bottom: `setPage(page + 1);`. This value is added in the api `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=15&_page=${page}`. 
Also i want to concat all data  from each scroll here: `return [...fetchedData, allData]`. At the end i need to achieve something like this:
User scrolls down and in the scroll section are added mew values, but previous   should't dissapear, so on every scrolling when the scroll bar is at the bottom the new data should be added at the bottom of the   select. 
Issue: I can't achieve what i described above and i don't know the issue.
Question: How to solve the issue in my situation?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-zsj6i?file=/example.js:0-1262

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";

const WithPromises = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [items, onItemsChange] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(page);
  }, [page]);

  const fetchData = async (pageIdx) => {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=15&_page=${pageIdx}`
    ).then((r) => r.json());
    const resItems = res.map(({ title }) => ({
      label: title,
      value: title
    }));
    onItemsChange([...items, ...resItems]);
  };

  const loadOptions = () => items;

  // for search functionality use something like this:
  // const loadOptions = async (inputStr) => {
  //   const searchRes = await fetch(`${yourUrl}?search=${inputStr}`).then(r => r.json());
  //   return searchRes;
  // };

  const handleBottomScroll = () => {
    setPage((prevVal) => prevVal + 1);
  };

  return (
    <AsyncSelect
      cacheOptions
      isClearable={true}
      isSearchable={true}
      defaultOptions={items}
      onMenuScrollToBottom={handleBottomScroll}
      loadOptions={loadOptions}
    />
  );
};

export default WithPromises;
```

Comment: your answer is great. I have one question, if i will implement a `search` feature on this, the options will be updated according to the searched value? PS: i want to keep the infinite scrolling also

Comment: to add support of "search" functionality you need to update `loadOptions` method. It should fetch data from API with search parameter and return it. You don't need to set it to state, just return.

Comment: according to jsonplaceholder documentation i can search  items by `id` like this:  `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=15&_page=${pageIdx}/${searchedId}`, but i changed code and it does not work.  You can see updateted sanbox

Comment: now you can see that if i search i don't get results in the dropdown. Could you please take a look why  the search does not work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you think about the issue?

Comment: you can't do two operations in the same time. Fetch OR paginated content OR by search criteria. In provided example you build URL incorrectly, by setting path after query params. Here's correct one: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${searchedId}?_limit=15&_page=${pageIdx}`

Comment: but in that case query params like "_limit" and "_page" will be ignored, because they haven't sense for direct call of item with provided ID

Comment: But anyway you should do OR `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${searchedId}` OR `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?_limit=15&_page=${pageIdx}`

Comment: i don't want to do 2 operations in the same time. I want to have search functionality when i will type in the search box and infinite scroll when i will scroll down. It is possible?

Comment: could you show in the sanbox how to do this? It will help me a lot.

Comment: If you want to handle both search and pagination, you need to move logic about collecting items data from `AsyncSelect` to parent component. I believe you can find already done solution for you: https://github.com/vtaits/react-select-async-paginate/tree/master/packages/react-select-async-paginate#page-way